# Floating label when input box contain some value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a  element in which the label floats upwards when the element is focused and goes back to original place when focus is removed.

Now if the input box contains some value and we remove the focus, the label should remain upwards only.
How can this be achieved using CSS?

jsbin Link: https://jsbin.com/furujub/edit?html,css,output

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

 <div class='floating_input'> 
  
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text">
    
    <label>Name</label>
  </div>
  
 </div>  

</body>
</html>
```

main.css

```
.floating_input {
  display: inline-block;
}
.field {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
label {
  order: -1;
  padding-left: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  pointer-events: none;
}
input:focus + label {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}
input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a very easy approach is to do the following : 
**1- add `required` to the input**

**2- edit the following lines:**

```
input:focus + label {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}
```

**to**

```
input:focus + label ,input:valid +label {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}
```

[see the edited code from here](https://jsbin.com/sayonepezu/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Just in case the original poster doesn't understand the code, it's basically saying while the input field is in focus, translate the label. Also, while the input is VALID (validation needs the "required" attribute), translate the label. Good work!